# proucedure of pheromone end its variation 2

Tags: netlogo

this is our procedure but we have a problem , the pheromone never be 0 and we need it to be 0
what should 'i do ?

```
LayPheromone

     if (pheromone < maxPheroPerSite-Forage)

        [set pheromone (pheromone + amtPheroLay-Forage)]

    end    
   to UpdatePatches
  ask patch nestX nestY [ set pcolor pink ]
 ask patches

[

if (pheromone < 0) [set pheromone 0]

if (pheromone > 0)

    [

    set pheromone (pheromone - pheromone * evaporation-rate)

    ifelse showPhero?
      [ set pcolor scale-color yellow pheromone 0 (maxPheroPerSite-Forage)]

      [ set pcolor black ]
    ]
] `
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the behavior that the intention behind this code and how it's failing to meet that intention? Have no clue what you mean or what kind of help you expect.

Comment: i'm working on application of avoid obstacle end my turtle use the pheromone( chemical ) to move. now , my problem is that the value of  pheromone never be 0 end i need it to be 0 , i did  this procedur but it does 't work ? please help me to find were is the mistake

Comment: There aren't any mistakes that I can see in the code you've posted. Perhaps the mistake is elsewhere.